# Have the cursed chests for the "old mill road" and the "cursed bellows" disappeared?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been trying to get the "old mill road" cursed chest and the cursed bellows. I have rerun both of those areas at least 100 times (literally) In the last month (5/2015) without seeing the chests. Has something changed in a recent update that would prevent those cursed events from loading? Can you only get them in another mode? Or do I just have the worst luck in the world? I have only been running in campaign.

Comment: Have you tried in Adventure Mode?

Comment: Cursed Bellows definitely spawns as a Bounty in Adventure mode. Not sure about Old Mill.

Answer (score 1):

Try in adventure mode when you have a bounty for that area, that's how I got it. The problem seems to be that certain cursed chests are only adventure mode based, and have an increase spawn chance when there's a bounty available for that region.

Comment: I will try adventure mode next. thank you for the information :)

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the answer if it works, it gives credit where credit is due!